# PHP - wrong order of array elements in case of hebrew letters

Tags: php, hebrew

That is my example code:

```
$string = '"5","תמר","0","N"';
var_dump(explode(',',$string));
```

That is the result:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) ""5""
  [1]=>
  string(8) ""תמר""
  [2]=>
  string(3) ""0""
  [3]=>
  string(3) ""N""
}
```

The order of elements is wrong. 3rd element is second. I understand that Hebrew is a language that we read RTL and it is the reason for switched order. 
How can I have got a proper order of elements, LTR for all of them?

Comment: I think there's a right to left align character that's misplaced there and covers the `0` part as well. if you try to select the "0" the hebrew characters get selected instead

Comment: Looping strpos also misbehave, could probably work but there could be some instances where it won't work. https://3v4l.org/Drd9H

Comment: What charset I should use? I tried different options.

Comment: I'm not going to post this as an answer since I believe there is a better solution (somehow), but it works for the string. https://3v4l.org/btBOv

Comment: Yeah, @Andreas that's not a stable solution, it doesn't allow any duplicate values to exist in the data.

Comment: I know. And I'm quite sure it won't work on other strings either.

Comment: @Ruben I think a re-think is in order here.  Can you tell us where the data is coming from and where it is going?

Comment: @mickmackusa File is downloaded from http://bar123.co.il. I take from them a list of cities and streets in Israel. Do you have any other idea how to resolve it? :D

Comment: I am thinking you need to partition (separate) the data into LTR and RTL, and handle them as separate processes entirely.  What comes next? Saving to database? Printing to screen?  Please share more details.

Comment: I save data to DB, unfortunately, part of fields contains both - LTR and RTL letters.